# I'd like to connect an LKETC USB Scypt Miner to my Raspberry Pi. Help?

Tags: mining-hardware, bfgminer, raspberry-pi

I am new to bitcoin mining, but pretty good with technology as a whole.  As a Father/Son project, I recently purchased a couple of USB LiteCoin Scrypt miners (I bought them here: http://www.aliexpress.com/item/free-shipping-hot-selling-litecoin-USB-miner-220kH-s-scrypt-miner-Litcoin-miner-send-out-in/2019121334.html ).  These have some drivers on them - they came with the Miner and are Windows based (or so they seem) - but I am strictly a Mac / Pi user.

So, I need some help in determining how to connect these Miners to a Pi or a Mac.

Can someone help me?
Many thanks in advance.....

Comment: I can't tell if these are miners or USB drives: `Capacity: 8G U disk`

Comment: AH.  I think they are a bit of both.  They come with a 8GB built-in storage capability (which shows up on my Mac Finder as a couple of folders with some apps and drivers.  The drivers are Silicon Lab - so I went to the web site here : https://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/USBtoUARTBridgeVCPDrivers.aspx  and found the MAC version of the drivers (installed them) and still no luck.  The device is a Miner by functions.  The memory is a small add-on.  Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

I think these might be rebranded ZeusMiner ASICs - LKETC doesn't appear to sell any scrypt miners below the 1MH/s range. Also, some of the reviews on that item say that they've had luck on linux with a fork of cgminer with ZeusMiner support.

There are two drivers you need. You need a driver for the USB-to-UART bridge, and a driver for the ASIC. The former is distributed with Raspbian, assuming the bridge is a Silicon Labs CP210x. (I think it is, based on the screenshots on that page.) The latter is usually distributed with your mining program of choice.

#### Possible fix

All instructions are intended for Debian/Ubuntu/Raspbian.

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libtool autotools-dev autoconf git
$ git clone https://github.com/dmaxl/cgminer/ && cd cgminer
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure --enable-scrypt --enable-zeus
$ make
$ ./cgminer
```

#### Troubleshooting (if that doesn't work)

When you plug it in, it should create the device /dev/ttyUSB1, and a device under /media or /mnt. You're interested in the first one.

You can get a list of devices that are plugged in with `lsusb`.

Comment: Hi, I have confirmed the drivers are Silicon Lab CP210x.  I have downloaded the Mac versions from here : https://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/USBtoUARTBridgeVCPDrivers.aspx.  I am going to try what you've typed out and see how it goes.  Is there a preferred Pi Image that I should start with to accomplish this?  I only have access to a NOOBS starter image, but I think I can figure out how to download and clone a new one (if you can point to one that is most appropriate).  Many thanks @NickODell.

Comment: HA, look what I found.  http://www.aliexpress.com/item/USB-Litecoin-miner-LTC-144KH-S-280KH-S-usb-miner-for-Asic-Miner-Collectibles-Christmas-gifts/32240507679.html.   This may not be rocket science, but perhaps it is helpful to you?  The images show a step-by-step process for Windows.  There is an app called LKController??  Do I need something like this for Pi / Mac to work?  How very odd.

Answer (score 1):

I build a custom driver wich allow to run lketc usb miner with other scrypt miner 
(originaly this driver is a zeus clone, but if you use lketc and zeus at same time one of miner not works)

you can download source code here : http://github.com/wareck/cgminer-lketc

and for windows user: http://github.com/wareck/cgminer-lketc/releases/download/cgminer-dragon-win32/cgminer-lketc-win32.zip

wareck

Answer (score 0):

Took me AWHILE to figure out how to make this cheap piece work with straight cgminer in linux...

First grab the cgminer version from https://github.com/dmaxl/cgminer/

After you configure it with --enable-scrypt and --enable-zeus...

sudo ./cgminer --scrypt --zeus-chips 1 --zeus-clock 200 -S /dev/ttyUSB0

Use lsusb to figure out what the USB # is and you can crank the clock from 200 - 300... maybe more... It'll get hot and need a fan, if you crank it up too much.

These LKETC USB miners are indeed using Zeus chips

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already solved this, but I got 2 of the 144KH/S-280KH/S USB LiteCoin miners running on my Mac - El Capitan by doing the following:

Download, build and install dmaxl/cgminer:

`./autogen.sh
./configure --scrypt --enable-zeus
make`

Find the USB sticks using:

`ls /dev/ | grep SLAB`


`cu.SLAB_USBtoUART
cu.SLAB_USBtoUART20
tty.SLAB_USBtoUART
tty.SLAB_USBtoUART20`

I tried both the tty.SLAB_USB* and cu.SLAB_USB* devices, only the cu.SLAB_USB* seem to work.  Make sure the switch is in the proper position on each USB stick (switches to the right)

Startup cgminer using the command:

`sudo ./cgminer --scrypt --zeus-chips 1 --zeus-clock 144  --zeus-nocheck-golden --url stratum+tcp://us.litecoinpool.org:3333 --user user --pass pass -S /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART -S /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART20`

The output looks like:

```
cgminer version 4.3.5-scrypt.2 - Started: [2016-02-10 13:28:56]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (5s):204.8K (1m):3.534M (5m):13.58M (15m):7.466M (avg):201.5Kh/s
 A:400  R:0  HW:0  WU:110.0/m
 Connected to us.litecoinpool.org diff 16 with stratum as user p0six.2
 Block: bf5105cb...  Diff:53.7K  Started: [13:32:12]  Best share: 570
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [U]SB management [P]ool management [S]ettings [D]isplay options [Q]uit
 0: ZUS cu.SLAB_USBt:    1 chips   144 MHz    | 98.30K / 98.29Kh/s WU:  0.0/m
 1: ZUS cu.SLAB_USBt:    1 chips   144 MHz    | 106.2K / 103.2Kh/s WU:110.0/m
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [2016-02-10 13:28:55] Found Zeus at /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART20, mark as 0
 [2016-02-10 13:28:55] ZUS0 opened on /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART
 [2016-02-10 13:28:55] ZUS1 opened on /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART20
 [2016-02-10 13:28:55] Probing for an alive pool
 [2016-02-10 13:28:55] Pool 0 difficulty changed to 1024
 [2016-02-10 13:28:56] Network diff set to 53.7K
 [2016-02-10 13:29:40] Pool 0 difficulty changed to 128
 [2016-02-10 13:29:40] Stratum from pool 0 requested work restart
 [2016-02-10 13:29:40] Stratum from pool 0 requested work restart
 [2016-02-10 13:29:55] Stratum from pool 0 requested work restart
 [2016-02-10 13:29:57] Stratum from pool 0 detected new block
 [2016-02-10 13:30:02] Stratum from pool 0 requested work restart
 [2016-02-10 13:30:19] Accepted 74e89353 Diff 561/128 ZUS 1
 [2016-02-10 13:30:30] Pool 0 difficulty changed to 16
 [2016-02-10 13:30:30] Stratum from pool 0 requested work restart
 [2016-02-10 13:30:36] Accepted 0f7528ed Diff 17/16 ZUS 1
 [2016-02-10 13:30:36] Accepted 0cd35843 Diff 20/16 ZUS 1
 [2016-02-10 13:30:37] Accepted 0e6b87d6 Diff 18/16 ZUS 1
 [2016-02-10 13:30:39] Accepted 0f759ff9 Diff 17/16 ZUS 1
 [2016-02-10 13:30:46] Accepted 077eb8cf Diff 34/16 ZUS 1
 [2016-02-10 13:30:47] Accepted 02072ca0 Diff 126/16 ZUS 1
 [2016-02-10 13:30:55] Stratum from pool 0 requested work restart
 [2016-02-10 13:31:00] Stratum from pool 0 requested work restart
 [2016-02-10 13:31:02] Accepted 72e164bb Diff 570/16 ZUS 1
 [2016-02-10 13:31:11] Stratum from pool 0 requested work restart
 [2016-02-10 13:31:13] Accepted 01064e29 Diff 250/16 ZUS 1
 [2016-02-10 13:31:24] Accepted 043989e0 Diff 61/16 ZUS 1
 [2016-02-10 13:31:30] Accepted 090f91cc Diff 28/16 ZUS 1
 [2016-02-10 13:31:31] Stratum from pool 0 requested work restart
 [2016-02-10 13:31:36] Accepted 0d552c6d Diff 19/16 ZUS 1
 [2016-02-10 13:31:38] Accepted 075f6dce Diff 35/16 ZUS 1
 [2016-02-10 13:31:54] Accepted 03582610 Diff 77/16 ZUS 1
 [2016-02-10 13:31:54] Accepted 03e27b84 Diff 66/16 ZUS 1
 [2016-02-10 13:31:59] Accepted 0ecb339a Diff 17/16 ZUS 1
 [2016-02-10 13:32:06] Accepted 0d200fb6 Diff 20/16 ZUS 1
 [2016-02-10 13:32:12] Stratum from pool 0 detected new block
 [2016-02-10 13:32:14] Stratum from pool 0 requested work restart
 [2016-02-10 13:32:17] Stratum from pool 0 requested work restart
 [2016-02-10 13:32:30] Accepted 01433148 Diff 203/16 ZUS 1
```

You can adjust the clock frequency, provided you have a fan.